# Android EditText highlighted while writing

Tags: android

I believe this problem is device specific (HTC H8 with lollipop). This also happens on Play Store and default SMS app

But when I'm writing on a EditText, the current word is highlighted until I hit space.
Any way to change this behavior?

[image]

Comment: I think i.e. because auto spell checker is on. if you off auto spell checker then word would not get highlighted

Comment: even i think this is keyboard setting problem

Comment: I would like to keep the suggestions, it is possible to change the color at least?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your EditText.

```
android:inputType"textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: I would like to keep the suggestions, it is possible to change the color at least?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to change the color, with this "android:textColorHighlight".

Comment: But this ins't "that" highlight, is the word suggestion, I believe I can't do anything related to that

Answer (score 0):

go to your phone setting>Language & input>disable spell checker

its behavior of your android system so only be disable from setting menu.

Comment: I would like to keep the suggestions, it is possible to change the color at least?